# WikiMiniAtlas: Using parameters leads to "Coordinates: Extra unexpected parameters"

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki

I want to add a "dim:" (Dimension) parameter to "coord" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakasu so that the [mini-map](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/WikiMiniAtlas) (click the globe in the upper-right) shows just the island (2 kilometers diameter), not the whole continent.

So I changed:

```
{{coord|35|37|N|139|50|E|display=title|region:JP_type:city_source:GNS-enwiki}}
```

... to:

```
{{coord|35|37|N|139|50|E|display=title|dim:2000|region:JP_type:city_source:GNS-enwiki}}
```

**PROBLEM:** I get an error `Coordinates: Extra unexpected parameters`.

What am I doing wrong? The [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template%3aCoord#dim%3aD) seems to imply it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WikiMiniAtlas developer here. Replace the `|` between 2000 and region with a `_`

```
{{coord|35|37|N|139|50|E|display=title|dim:2000_region:JP_type:city_source:GNS-enwiki}}
```

That should work.

Comment: Thanks, I modified https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakasu like you said, and that works! Huge thanks for WikiMiniAtlas by the way! :-)